# Address pointer to its ascii representation in C

Tags: c

I have a function pointer

```
void *p_func = &func;
```

How can i manage to write the address in a file as ASCII characters representing the hex value in C language ?

e.g if my function address is 0x41424344, then how can i write

> "\x41\x42\x43\x44"

to the file ? (which would give "ABCD" when the file is catted)

Comment: Did  you mean to use the "%p" format string in fprintf?

Comment: Do you just want `41424344` written to your output (which would be `ABCD` if read bytes by byte from the file as hex)?

Comment: use `"%p"` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit verbose, but is probably the most readable.

```
const uintptr_t func_value = (uintptr_t) &func;
fprintf(file, "%c%c%c%c",
       (char)(func_value >>  0 & 0xFF),
       (char)(func_value >>  8 & 0xFF),
       (char)(func_value >> 16 & 0xFF),
       (char)(func_value >> 24 & 0xFF));
```

Or maybe just fwrite:

```
fwrite(&func, sizeof(uintptr_t), 1, file);
```

Comment: Would that be `"\\x%c\\x%c\\x%c\\x%c"` in the exact format specified? (though it would not be `"ABCD"`) I don't fully understand which way the OP wants it, but just a thought based on one read.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i manage to write the address in a file as ASCII characters representing the hex value in C language ?

Use the standard printing specifier to print a `void *` pointer.

```
printf("%p", p_func);
```

To be portable you could use `uintptr_t` and print as `uintmax_t` to print a function pointer:

```
printf("%jx", (uintmax_t)(uintptr_t)&function);
```

Or maybe you want to serialize the function pointer value as bytes - so alias it with `unsigned char` and print it in big endian:

```
void (*p_func)() = &function;
unsigned char *bytes = p_func;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(p_func); ++i) {
    printf("%02x", bytes[i]);
}
```

or in little endian depending on your platform.

> if my function address is 0x41424344, then how can i write to the file ? (which would give "ABCD" when the file is catted)

Instead of `printf("%02x"` above print the byte as it is with `printf("%c"` or just `putchar` or `putc`. Note that it may not be an ASCII character.

> I have a function pointer

`p_func` is a normal `void *` pointer, not a function pointer.

Side note - a conversion between a function pointer to a `void *` pointer is technically not allowed per C standard and just be aware that it's your compiler extensions.

Comment: Wouldn't that print `"0x41424344"` when they're asking for the output to be `"ABCD"`?

Comment: That's another way to go. I'm still not entirely sure what exact bytes the OP wants written.

Comment: Well i'm sorry I find it hard to explain. To be clear : i'm erasing an EIP with a string. I need that string to be the address to my function. And i can't manage to find a way to write that as a proper string that'll be interpreted as my address..

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask about that, not about XY question. I do not understand - what does "erasing EIP with a string" could mean? You can write a number to EIP. `as a proper string that'll be interpreted as my address` To read a pointer just `scanf("%p"` it the same why you `printf("%p"`ed it (and similar with `%jx` or `%02x` to `scanf`). But I do not follow, just `fread` and `fwrite` it then anyway.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, I thought that generalizing on where I'm struggling would be more helpful than explaining exactly what i'm trying to achieve.
I'd like to write to that file like i could do str = "\x41\x42\x43\x44", and then write that str to a file in python.

Comment: So use `fwrite` and write the bytes, as they are, to file. But remember about endianess (or not, if you are going to read the data on the same platform)